# Matrices in systems of linear equations

Tags: matrices, determinant, systems-of-equations

I've been working on matrices lately. Currently, I am stuck on solving systems of linear equations using matrices. I've read the following article which has proved very helpful in understanding the basics of matrices intuitively: [An Intuitive Guide to Linear algebra](https://betterexplained.com/articles/linear-algebra-guide/), however, one thing still confuses me. In the following illustrations,
[image: pic]
[image: A picture]

One thing still confuses me. If the "operations" matrix and the "input data" matrix are switched, then the output changes. Therefore, I conclude they matrices are not commutative, but in the following example:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
3 &2  &1 \\ 
 2& 3 &4 \\ 
2 & 6 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x\\ y
\\z 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}5
\\ 31
\\ 43
\end{bmatrix}$$
But say I want to multiply both sides of the matrix by a certain matrix.
$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\5\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

are both these operations valid?

this:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\5\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
3 &2  &1 \\ 
 2& 3 &4 \\ 
2 & 6 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x\\ y
\\z 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\5\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}5
\\ 31
\\ 43
\end{bmatrix}$$

...and this:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
3 &2  &1 \\ 
 2& 3 &4 \\ 
2 & 6 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x\\ y
\\z 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\5\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}5
\\ 31
\\ 43
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\5\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Anyways, can anyone explain to me how I can simplify,$$\begin{bmatrix}
3 &2  &1 \\ 
 2& 3 &4 \\ 
2 & 6 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
into an identity matrix.

In other words, how can I simplify a system of linear equations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> are both these operations valid

No. I think what you want to do is right-multiply both sides by a $3\times 3$ matrix whose diagonal elements are  $2,5,1$.

Comment: That didn't work. I tried it.